# Sqlite database connectected to a python file is causing errors when imported as a package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sqlite database and a python file in a folder. Now I'm trying to access that as a package but I run into this error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:projects` where as the same thing works fine when I run that a single python file.

I have created one **init**.py empty file inside the folder
The code runs perfectly when I m running that python file
database name is **project.db** and the table name is **projects**

I red about documentation on modules and packages but not able to understand the problem. I need help in understanding the problem and also any reference to writing our own python packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your project structure exactly, but my best guess is that in your python file with the code you reference the `database.db` with a relative path like that

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
```

When you import that file from another python file the new python file is started in its directory and the relative path to your database is wrong. You can easily check that by printing `os.getcwd()` ("cwd" = current working directory).

The solution is to use an absolute path or change the current working directory with `os.chdir(path)` before using the python file that opens the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I know this was silly to ask but you saved me a lot of time.